# How to place UIView at top using Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I want to place UIView at the top of view controller using autolayout ,I have tried a lot, the UIView height is getting small in iPhone 4 and large in iphone 6 & above , how can i fix ? [Attached image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuYIw.png)

Comment: what you want ,fix size of uiview ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can understand from your question, If you need fix size of Subview on top then don't give bottom spacing constrain.

Please set constrain as shown in below image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think if you add a `height constraint` to that view and it will fix your issue .For setting`height constraint` check this link
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html